# ListView line filling half screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to built a ListView which has a line per player.
Each line should be very small but instead it is filling the whole screen with 2 massive lines.

[image]

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer" android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:content="@+id/contentLayout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#000000">
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
                android:src="@drawable/blue_arrow_up_flat"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/contentLayout" android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvwScores" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:divider="#FFFFFF" android:dividerHeight="1dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true" android:headerDividersEnabled ="true"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayerName"  android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/tvwPlayerScore" android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use ListView for this? do you have a list of items you want to be able to scroll through?

Comment: It's a list of players in the game with their scores. There could be up to nine so there is big chance that they will not fit on one screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing android:layout_weight="1" of ListView to 3 or >3..Might work out..

Answer (score 0):

I think the ListView is drawn correctly.
You can see the two lines, the only problem is that they are drawn in the center and therefore look like they span the whole screen.

So I assume if you remove

```
android:gravity="center"
```

from your LinearLayout it should work.

And as a sidenote:
I never worked with SlidingDrawer, but its documentation states that you should use `match_parent` ( or `fill_parent` ) for its width and height. I assume you do not want to let the SlidingDrawer span over the whole screen if there is almost no content. Maybe this class does not allow other behavior, I do not know. But maybe this is the real source for your problem and not the ListView itself.

Edit:
Disregard my sidenote, the SlidingDrawer is drawn ontop with the blank area being transparent, therefore there should be no problem with its look...